# Count to first column and sum to the rest of the columns pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a pandas DataFrame `df` with 290 columns.

Is there a way to make the `.groupby` operation concerning the following rules:

1. sum operation for the 2st column.
2. count operation to 3nd column.
3. mean operation to all other columns

I know that I could use like this:

```
df.groupby("column1") \
    .agg({"column2":"sum", 
          "column3":"count",
          "column4":"mean",
          ...
          "column290":"mean"})
```

But using this way is totally unproductive, since I have to type all the other columns.

Is there a way to set this operation? Like setting a default function when I don't set any to agg?

Comment: Kindly add sample data with expected output

Answer (score 1):

Let's use a dictionary:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame(np.arange(100).reshape(10,-1), columns=[*'ABCDEFGHIJ'])

# Defined the first three columns  
aggdict={'A':'sum',
         'B':'sum',
         'C':'count'}

# Use for loop to added to dictoary the rest of the columns. Creating a 
# default aggregation method
for i in df.columns[3:]:
    aggdict[i]='mean'

# Use agg with dictionary
df.groupby(df.index%2).agg(aggdict)
```

Comment: The grouper needs to be just for the first column.

Answer (score 0):

```
df1=df.groupby("column1").agg({"column2":"sum", "column3":"count"})

df2=df.drop(["column2", "column3"], 1).groupby("column1").agg("mean", 1)

df3=pd.concat([df1, df2], 1)
```